# jQuery / Select2 Initialization Issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Looking for some assistance with a jQuery initialisation issue.

I have a HTML Select control on my page as follows;

```
<select class="ItemFilter" name="filters[]" multiple="multiple">
<optgroup label="Fruit">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Vegetable">
    <option value="Avocado">Avocado</option>
    <option value="Lettuce">Lettuc</option>
</optgroup>
```

The jQuery for my Select2 is as follows, and loads perfectly fine when you load the page. It's formatted properly and works really well.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ItemFilter').select2({
        placeholder: "Select some filters to apply..",
    });
});
```

**The issue I have:**
When I click another button somewhere else on the page which updates a database with some detail, the Select control loses it's 'Select2' connection, meaning it reverts back to a standard Select control without the Select2 formatting and functionality. It's worth noting that the area of the page I am updating some detail is contained within an UpdatePanel (UpdateMode- Always).

Any pointers or ideas on what I can do to fix this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When an UpdatePanel is triggered and refreshes (known as a *partial postback*), it re-renders all of its content. As you've noted, this will result in the elements being recreated from scratch.

You could add a `<script>` block to your `UpdatePanel` that triggers a function on partial postbacks, re-enabling the Select2 functionality.

Something like this should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  onUpdatePanelPostback();
});

function onUpdatePanelPostback() {
  $('.ItemFilter').select2({
    placeholder: "Select some filters to apply..",
  });
}
```

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
  <ContentTemplate>

    <script>
      Sys.Application.add_load(onUpdatePanelPostback);
    </script>

    <select class="ItemFilter" name="filters[]" multiple="multiple"> 
      ... 
    </select>

  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```